# Can not load VALIDATE dataset

Tags: google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

I can load the TRAIN and TEST dataset, but the set of VALIDATE can not be loaded.

What I have tried:
I loaded a dataset including 80% of TRAIN, 10% of TEST, 10% of VALIDATE, and the total amount of photos is 8567. However, it says: Error: ROW_URI_MISSING: Invalid input found at row 126 of gs://digit_for_standard_number/datatocsv.csv: "No GCS uri found."

Then I moved all the VALIDATE photos to TEST, leaving only the dataset of TRAIN and TEST, and they were successfully loaded, although I can not start my training without the VALIDATE set.

Here are some parts of my csv file:
TRAIN,gs://digit_for_standard_number/Sample003/img004-00005.png,4
TEST,gs://digit_for_standard_number/Sample007/img008-00005.png,8
VALIDATE,gs://digit_for_standard_number/Sample007/img008-00011.png,8

If you know how to solve this problem, please tell me. Appreciate it!

Comment: Later, I solved this by using UNASSIGNED instead of VALIDATE, and it worked successfully!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this indeed looks like a temporary bug.

Change "VALIDATE" to "UNASSIGNED"

Comment: This solution is still valid 2022

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNASSIGNED, TEST, TRAIN or VALIDATION